# Alone, locked inside an empty and dark room. From where to start eating oneself?

Tags: survival

If I was locked in a empty room which is completely dark, from which body part should I start eating my body to maximize the survival time?

Also can we survive longer if we eat our flesh or keep drinking our own blood ?

Comment: Why is it relevant that the room is completely dark?

Comment: @Bebs , to keep the option of eating eyes ..

Comment: If you have absolutely no water income (body fluids will not be enough), you will die from thirst before having the necessity to eat one of your own body part.

Comment: And if you have no decent toilets, the risk of infection after you wound yourself will be very high and kill you before the days you would gain.

Comment: So, how are the hygiene means in the room, and do you have water income (like water runoff on walls...)?

Comment: Immune System: "We're already dialed back to survival levels from lack of food and water and now body parts are going missing? Some days it just doesn't pay to climb out of the lymph nodes."

Comment: @Bebs empty room.

Comment: Your best bet is to keep all your limbs and focus on the door.  The thing about kicking in doors is that most people give up too soon. Even a very solid seeming door when struck over and over again can develope deformations and microfractures in the frame, joining hardware, and even the door itself which weaken it over time.  Once you start hacking yourself up, escape becomes a non-option.

Comment: Remember when people always asked me about having weird questions? Hindsight huh?

Comment: As pointed out in the top answer so far, there's not really any point to chopping off a body part and sending it to your stomach, when the body *already has* the ability to feed on that body part right where it is. This question gets a lot more interesting if you're paired with a cellmate you can eat, but whom you don't want to spoil by killing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are already eating yourself without needing any conscious act. When your body needs energy, it starts to consume your fat reserves (that's what they're for), then your muscles and all the rest, in order of increasing importance for survival.

Biting off anything would not do you any good.

Comment: It'll also be hard to build up the enthusiasm to eat yourself. People aren't wired that way (and don't need to be, for exactly the reason you've just given).

Comment: I think the trauma of eating one's own limbs might outdo the gains granted by eating said limbs too.

Comment: Digestion is less efficient than fat usage anyways, so not only is eating yourself traumatic but also wasteful.

Comment: First world problems.  People in the third world already know how to starve; nobody needs to tell them their body does it automagically.

Answer (score 15):

Septicemia or thirst will kill you before starvation can. It doesn't matter where you start biting.

In a room with no means of disinfection and no way of taking rid of your own wastes, as soon as you bite off part of your body you will start bleeding and the wound will get in touch with your own feces/urine.

At this point you will either get an infection that will kill you, or the loss of liquid consequent to the bleeding will lead you to a fatal result.

Comment: Unless the room is tiny, or you literally sit in your own filth, infecting yourself before you die of thirst is likely to prove challenging.

Comment: @StarfishPrime with no toiler paper around one IS literally sitting on his own filth.

Comment: Depends on their diet and current clothing, no? But this is rapidly and unpleasantly getting off-topic, which is quite an achievement, given the topic...

Answer (score 5):

Someone has been reading [*Survivor Type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivor_Type), I see...

As interestingly macabre as the concept is, your body already handles this for you.  During [starvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation), your body progressively consumes first fat reserves and then muscle.  Whilst there are still some calories left in the remaining skin and bone, your body will use more resources to heal any wounds than it would gain from consuming them.  So you're better to sit tight, try not to expend energy, and wait for rescue.

Lack of water will kill you first, of course.  It is unclear whether [drinking your own urine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urophagia) will improve your survival, given the dissolved salts in it, in the same way as drinking seawater would not help.  With the aid of a still, you could possibly purify your urine and survive longer, although of course water lost through perspiration cannot be recovered.  A traditional underground dungeon does tend to have damp walls though, so you may survive longer by licking the walls or metal fittings for moisture.

Comment: Good with one exception: I think it is fairly clear that urine drinking is not a valid survival strategy. It is toxic, and I have read claims that doing this could possibly kill you faster than not doing it, or that even if you do live a day or two longer it will be at the expense of having killed your kidneys so that you're just walking-dead anyway even if you could start drinking water after that.

Answer (score 3):

Eyes. You need liquid because you will die of dehydration. And you don't need eyes to see things.

Your main problem would be that you have no way of measuring time. So there is no way to say "If I won't drink now and I will go to sleep I will not wake up". Because you can sleep 5 times for 15 minutes and only 24 hours will fly.

Comment: I am not sure two eyeballs contain more water than a full bladder.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica I assume the content of bladder and bowels were preemptied before entering the room. Also there is a health question - what fluid is better: 800mls of urine or one from two eyeballs (ignoring potential infection).

Comment: Assuming the eyeballs could be 'retrieved' without great damage, losing their benefits without having any proper utensils to remove them with.

Comment: +1'ed @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica comment, but just in case some people don't get the exaggeration I'm pointing out that we are sure two eyeballs contain less water than a full bladder (/capt.-obv.). Even if all bladder and bowel contents were preemptied as SZCZERZO suggests, the bladder will still have more anyway since it is filling all the time, even if you are dying of thirst your body still requires some urine output. However, urine is **NOT** a source of survival-situation water; it is toxic. Still, I think eating your eyes provides negligible benefit and could potentially kill you faster.